# WPF Ribbon not displaying correctly in Designer

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, ribbon

I'm using Microsoft's built-in Ribbon class (System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon) and VS2015 Pro. The ribbon I've created does not display correctly in the visual designer. Is that normal or am I missing something?

[image: This is what the mutilated ribbon display I get]

I've been able to set up the entire Ribbon in XAML, which I'm used to using anyway. But as the mess at the top becomes bigger as I add more elements, I'd love a correct preview. Any tips?

Comment: I'll post a sanitized XAML in a bit. But this happens even when there is no Binding on any ribbon elements at all.

Comment: Or maybe not? Comment was removed :)